# connecting multiple javascript "class" objects to html div elements

Tags: jquery, html, oop, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask

I'm writing a web app using Flask+Jinja2+Bootstrap 3, using Jquery to control a lot of the UI interaction I want to do.  However I'm adding new functionality that is proving to be quite complex, and I fear my current way of writing is sub-par.  Currently I have a site with many div's (created via a jinja2 loop).  Each div has a unique id.  Inside each div, I have a multi-layered div network, but I gave them one id (perhaps mistakenly).  So when it looped it created many of the same structure with the same id, embedded inside the unique ones.

E.g.

```
<div class='galinfo' id='gal_uniqid1'>
   <div class='panel' id='qapanel'>
       <select id='qaselect'>...
       <button id='qabutton'>...
   </div>
</div>

<div class='galinfo' id='gal_uniqid2'>
   <div class='panel' id='qapanel'>
       <select id='qaselect'>...
       <button id='qabutton'>...
   </div>
</div>

<div class='galinfo' id='gal_uniqid3'>
   <div class='panel' id='qapanel'>
       <select id='qaselect'>...
       <button id='qabutton'>...
   </div>
</div>

etc...
```

Inside these divs I have a bunch of jquery functions that run when various buttons are clicked, options are selected, toggles are toggled, etc. All of the functionality inside each unique div is the same. However, I started to realize that

1.) I find myself having to select the same things over and over across the multiple functions

2.) This doesn't work well where my ids are the same.  Selecting on id='qabutton' only grabs the first element in the list, which is for id='gal_uniaid1'.  I have to resort to long complicated selects like $(#gal_uniqid2 qabutton) to grab the one I want.

3.) This might be easier if I incorporate all the loosely scattered jquery functions into one jQuery class object.

What I'd like to do is build one generic jQuery object that I can instantiate, and attach to each unique div.  E.g. a class called Qainfo(), then do something like

qainfo = Qainfo(id='gal_uniqid1') , and attach it somehow to my id='gal_uniqid1' div.  Similarly, I'd have qainfo = Qainfo(id='gal_uniqid2') on the 2nd div.

Then I could call my methods directly, qainfo.dobuttonstuff(), qainfo.writeStuff(), etc, and it knows inside the class to establish all the right nested links, ultimately which unique div I'm currently on, which panels and buttons correspond to what, etc.

Is something like this possible? Thanks.

Comment: HTML id attributes must be unique. Why not just use a class? Then one jQuery selector will pick them all up?

Comment: Yeah I know the ids must be unique, but that would require rather long appended ids that I have to select by hand, and significant rewriting. Classes will select everything which is what I don't want to do.  I only want to select a div one at a time.  Rather than having to manually specify a long unique id nested way down into my main div, I was hoping for an elegant way to select an upper level jQuery object, where the nested div mappings are already created during instantiation, so it's easier to do selections.

Comment: In short, yes, this is completely possible, although without the rest of the code it's difficult to point you in the right direction.

Comment: That's a tall order.  It's a lot of code, scattered across multiple files.  Should I just dump it all here?  Or can you suggest some stuff to give you an idea?